# Inserting into custom SQL types with prepared statements in java

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, prepared-statement

I have some custom types. They are all basically enums. Here is an example of what they look like:

```
CREATE TYPE card_suit AS ENUM
   ('spades',
    'clubs',
    'hearts',
    'diamonds');
```

And I have some prepared statements in Java, which look something like this:

```
// Setup stuff up here.
sql = "INSERT INTO foo (suit) VALUES (?)";
st.setString(1, 'spades');
st.executeUpdate(sql);
```

And Java gives me some nasty exceptions like this:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "suit" is of type card_suit but expression is of type character varying
Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

It's nice of them to give me a hint, but I'm not sure exactly how to follow it.

Comment: If you have control of the schema, a check constraint on a text column can work the same as the enum, yet is easier to work with in Java.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Have you tried to cast column to enum?

```
// Setup stuff up here.
sql = "INSERT INTO foo (suit) VALUES (?::card_suit)";
st.setString(1, 'spades');
st.executeUpdate(sql);
```

Explained in [Convert between Java enums and PostgreSQL enums](http://www.gotoquiz.com/web-coding/programming/java-programming/convert-between-java-enums-and-postgresql-enums/) article of 'A web coding blog' with samples:

```
INSERT INTO pet (pet_id, pet_type, name) 
         VALUES (?, CAST(? AS animal_type), ?);

--or

INSERT INTO pet (pet_id, pet_type, name) 
         VALUES (?, ?::animal_type, ?);
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Haven't used casting in SQL before. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would have been

```
st.setObject(1, 'spades', Types.OTHER);
```