# How to cast string value to enum

Tags: postgresql, casting, enums

I have a table with an `enum` type in it, and I created a function to add data to that table. I want that function to be generous in what to accept, so I take a `text` as the enum type and want to cast it later.

This is the enum:

```
CREATE TYPE public.enum_log_priority AS ENUM (
    'critical','error','warning','notice','debug'
);
```

And this is the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.log_write(
    _message text,
    _priority text
) RETURNS integer AS
$body$
BEGIN
    _priority = lower(_priority);
    INSERT INTO log (message, priority) VALUES (_message, _priority);

    RETURN 0;
END
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

I know this doesn't work:

> ERROR:  column "priority" is of type enum_log_priority but expression is of type text

but how can I do this?

Comment: Please specify the structure of enum_log_priority with all possible values

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Use syntax like below during insertion

```
'critical'::enum_log_priority
```

Please see some link as well

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-enum.html

[Inserting into custom SQL types with prepared statements in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10571821/inserting-into-custom-sql-types-with-prepared-statements-in-java)

[java enum and postgresql enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16492370/java-enum-and-postgresql-enum)

Answer (score 5):

change your function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.log_write(
    _message text,
    _priority text
) RETURNS integer AS
$body$
BEGIN
    _priority = lower(_priority);
    INSERT INTO log (message, priority) VALUES (_message, _priority::enum_log_priority);

    RETURN 0;
END
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

[**| sql fiddle demo |**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/f1da1/1)

Answer (score 5):

Postgres supports also the cast function:

```
cast(priority AS enum_log_priority);
```

Comment: not working for me, same error

Comment: please post a question stating what you tried, which error you get and reference this answer

Comment: "ERROR: column "type" is of type geotargettypenum but expression is of type text"
with cast(type AS geotargettypeenum);

ENUM is 

create type geotargettypeenum as enum ('ADMIN_ZONE', 'BUFFER', 'INSEE_CODE', 'IRIS_CODE', 'POLYGON', 'POSTAL_CODE');

Comment: Not here. You need to write your own question.

Comment: you don't need the cast, your expression is not an enum, but a text

Answer (score 0):

Consider that sometimes (for example in Prisma raw queries) you need to put the enum type inside quotations.

```
'critical'::"enum_log_priority"
```